# Add image icon to left of ordered list number

Tags: css, position, visibility, bulletedlist

### The issue

I already know how to add image bullets using the CSS `background-image` property. What I'm trying to do now is display a little graphic icon to the left of the line number in an ordered list.

The issue I keep running into is that when trying to place the image bullet it doesn't show on the screen. I can see that it is there by nudging the image along the X-axis to the right, so I don't know what it is not displaying correctly.

Note: I **can** get the icon to appear to the right of the number, before the text, but that is not the desired result.

### My code

```css
.action-item {
    background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/clipboard-1/100/clipboard-10-512.png);
    background-position: -4px 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-size: 1.4em;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-indent: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="action-item">item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li class="action-item">item 4</li>
  <li class="action-item">item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
</ol>
```

### What I've tried already

I have tried configuring `text-indent`, `padding-left`, `margin-left`, `line-height`, all to no avail.

### Ideas I haven't tried

- `overflow: hidden`
- `z-index`

### My question

Is this possible with pure CSS, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) and the before pseudo element:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: orderedlist;
}
ol > li {
  counter-increment: orderedlist;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
ol > li:before {
  content: counter(orderedlist)".";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.52em;
}
.action-item {
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/clipboard-1/100/clipboard-10-512.png);
  background-position: -4px 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="action-item">item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li class="action-item">item 4</li>
  <li class="action-item">item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks Pete! That is exactly what I wanted :) You are a lifesaver! I have marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010, just thought with the above solution, if the text wraps 2 lines, the number will get lost in it.  Here is a better solution - a bit more padding and negative margin on the number: https://jsfiddle.net/8k5373kj/1/